# Should be Triggers inactive by default in Unit Tests?

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice

Apex Triggers can cause problems when developers need to create test data. This is because triggers can execute a lot of logic, such as validation, API callouts, and multiple SOQL and DML statements (which have limits).
**This can make it difficult to create test data when triggers are active, and can lead to long running unit tests.**

So the question is: **Should triggers be inactive by default in Unit Tests?**
This can be achieved using trigger frameworks, which allow developers to turn on triggers only when necessary (such as to test handlers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Soapbox

A well-regarded way of doing unit tests is to implement the Separation of Concerns pattern (as espoused by [Salesforce Platform Enterprise Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BD8TBT75))

Coupled with mocking of the relevant layers - domain, service, selector (see [ApexMocks](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks) or [Amoss](https://github.com/bobalicious/amoss) or [Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm))

This approach allows one to isolate testing without having to build elaborate  DML setup data and to avoid external side effects.  The result - a faster and focused set of real unit tests.

Now of course, you still need to have apex tests for integration but a lot fewer of these once you've proven that the individual testable units work as expected (don't forget those asserts!)

Triggers should always be active but for testing purposes, you may need dependency injection to shut off certain service layer items (say, to prevent callouts). Do this not by disabling triggers but by switching off the specific logic.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is very interesting question!
I would say - **no, triggers shouldn't be inactive by default**, because during code execution they are active, aren't they? So your tests should "simulate" similar environment which user has during code execution. But this sounds like a perfect world.
World is not perfect tho. When the org is old, n+ developers wrote code which isn't perfect (to put it mildly) - and as you said - it's hard to avoid hitting limits, tests are taking forever... I think in those situations developer **should be aware** of that he's turning off triggers for unit tests.

Answer (score -1):

You can see a good, implicit example of how you might separate business logic from the `trigger` component itself, through the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) package. Below is a sample, *automatically* generated trigger and a test class that provides 100% coverage.

```java
/**
 * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs)
 **/
trigger dlrs_outfunds_DisbursementTrigger on outfunds__Disbursement__c
    (before delete, before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update)
{
    dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler(outfunds__Disbursement__c.SObjectType);
}
```

```java
/**
 * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs)
 **/
@IsTest
private class dlrs_outfunds_DisbursementTest
{
    @IsTest
    private static void testTrigger()
    {
        // Force the dlrs_outfunds_DisbursementTrigger to be invoked, fails the test if org config or other Apex code prevents this.
        dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new outfunds__Disbursement__c());
    }
}
```

The trigger is fully covered, and you can see the test implies there's no need for the *trigger* test to know what `triggerHandler` actually does.